# Find and replace with form input in javascript problems

Tags: javascript, for-loop, replace

I'm trying to make a find and replace function with form user input. Using the form user can specify word to be replaced and the replacement. After replacing is finished, additionally I want an alert with replaced words count to pop up. I figured I should do it with `for` loop. I'm not advanced enough to use jQuery yet, so that's why I went for plain JS.

```
function wordReplace()
{
   var replaced = document.getElementById('replaced').value.toLowerCase;
   var replacement = document.getElementById('replacement').value;
   var workArea = document.getElementById('main');
   for (var r=0; r<workArea.lenght; r++)
       {
           if (workArea[r].value.toLowerCase == '\breplaced')
               {
                   workArea[r].value.replace('\breplaced' '\breplacement')
                   alert(workArea[r].value.replace('replaced' 'replacement').length)
               }
       }    
}
```

But I can't even check if that's correct (would be surprised if it is) because I got `missing ) after argument list` error in `workArea[r].value.replace('\breplaced' '\breplacement')` line.
What's even worse, all other scripts I wrote to this point stopped working because of it too.

So basically I've got two questions:

- What should I do to get the function working
- What should I do to fix the `missing ) after argument list` thingie.

All and any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are commas missing in the replace

```
workArea[r].value.replace('\breplaced' '\breplacement')
alert(workArea[r].value.replace('replaced' 'replacement').length)
```

should be

```
workArea[r].value.replace('\breplaced', '\breplacement')
alert(workArea[r].value.replace('replaced', 'replacement').length)
```

Comment: It took care of `missing ) after argument list` error nicely. Fixing up the function itself to get it running left to go :) Thank You very much!